# Difference in results returned between .has() and :has()

Tags: jquery

I have a gnarly navigation structure that can be generalized as:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>
        A
        <ul>
            <li>
                B
                <ul>
                    <li>C</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                D
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        E
                        <ul>
                            <li>F</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Sub-items are hidden until hover.  I want to indicate that B, D, and E have sub-items by styling them so I used the selector:

```
$('#navigation > li li:has(ul)')
```

Which only returned B and D.  Changing it to:

```
$('#navigation > li li').has('ul')
```

returned all of the correct items but I'm confused as to why.

**EDIT**

`:has()` doesn't appear to be affected (entirely) by nesting as

```
$('#navigation ul > li:has(ul)')
```

returns the same results as `.has()` above.

Comment: It seems to me that the results should be the same. I don't know why they're different. Perhaps Sizzle gives up looking in nested elements when a match is found. If so, this would seem to ignore the possibility of identical nested elements (as you have in your example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the jQuery API documentation:

> [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selects elements which
>   contain at least one element that
>   matches the specified selector.
>
> [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) reduces the set of
>   matched elements to those that have a
>   descendant that matches the selector
>   or DOM element.

There is a related question here: [jQuery: subtle difference between .has() and :has()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944878/jquery-subtle-difference-between-has-and-has) , that seems to point to what the difference in the two could be.

However, It appears that `:has` doesn't look within a match in a nested fashion while `.has()` does because it returns a subset of matches as a jQuery object is able to match all descendants, even the nested one, like a regular jQuery selector.

Comment: Those are the descriptions copied from the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/has/). How does it make them different? It would seem to me that they should return the same results.

Comment: The link you posted is specific to an issue where the selector starts with `>`.

Comment: I have to agree with @patrick - this doesn't at all answer the question, the `:has()` description means it *should* find that third element, `E`.  Also, you should like to where these descriptions come from.

Comment: I think the link gives us a clue as to what might be going on regarless of the specific use of the child selector

Comment: @Moin - Not really. The opposite is true in that question. There, the `:has()` selector version works, and the `.has()` method doesn't. In fact the method returns `0` results. Different issue.

Comment: @Nick - I've got a new strategy getting for rep points. Plagiarize docs, post unrelated links, and re-word other people's comments. I'll catch up to you before you know it. ;o)

Comment: @patrick - heh true in this case...the question does have me figuring out where the issue is in Sizzle though, it seems to be a post processing step that goes astray, will answer when I can explain it better.

Comment: @patrick: I didn't even read your comment under the Q until after I posted, if the strategy as you've stated works in a collaboratively edited site, with folks like you around, then there's something else wrong...

@Nick: Might be useful to post your findings in the ticket the poster from the other Q created: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7205

Answer (score 0):

The [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selects only those elements that have descending elements that are matched by the given selector. Internally, [`:has` is defined](http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L523) as ([Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) is jQuery default selector library):

```
function(elem, i, match){
    return !!Sizzle( match[3], elem ).length;
}
```

This is nearly equivalent to testing `jQuery("selector", elem).length` or `jQuery(elem).find("selector").length` for each selected element to filter those that don’t have such descendants.

In contrast to that, the [`has` method](http://api.jquery.com/has/) can take either a selector or a DOM element and returns only those elements that do not contain any of the given elements. Because internally, the [`has` method is defined](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L35) as:

```
function( target ) {
    var targets = jQuery( target );
    return this.filter(function() {
        for ( var i = 0, l = targets.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            if ( jQuery.contains( this, targets[i] ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So it uses the [`contains` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) to check if the given elements are contained to filter the selected elements. Note that it suffices that only one of the given elements are contained.

Comment: This doesn't explain the behavior though, this is a bug in Sizzle as it *should* return these elements, the problem is the array of selector parts being popped incorrectly in this scenario.  For example: `$('#navigation li li:has(ul)')` will give 3 elements.